# How to swap 2 objects using template function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, swap

How to swap 2 objects using template function ??? I just want to swap the age number between 2 objects from same class using template function called `my_swap()`.

```
struct Men
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
}
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os,const Men &M)
{
    os << M.name;
    return os;
}


template <typename T>
void my_swap(T &a,T &b)
{
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b= temp;
}

int main()
{
    int x{100};
    int y{200};
    my_swap(x,y);
    std::cout << x << "," << y << std::endl;
}
```

What I want to do is:

```
Men M1{"Jack", 10};
Men M2{"Tony", 20};
Men M3 = my_swap(M1, M2);
```

Comment: `my_swap` has return type `void`, so what exactly are you expecting to receive in `M3`?

Comment: You can use `std::swap`, as it is a template function.  Already tested and debugged. :-)

Comment: so if i use T &my_swap(T &a,T &b) , is this work also with primitive types?? also i think i need to change the function implementation to be a.name and b.name. i think i can't make this function to be template function for my own classes and primitive types at same time

Comment: OT: `my_swap` shoud use _move semantics_, otherwise it would be terribly inefficient.

Comment: You say you want it to just swap the ages, buy you also say you want it to work with primitive types - which of course don't have an age. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, what would you want M3 to be set to in your example?

Comment: Yes @ROX this is correct , i can get rid of M3 , i only want to implement real template function that can work with all primitive types and also my user defined classes

Answer (score 1):

Your template is already good to do this, you just have to pass the `age` member in the call, leaving the template as is:

```
int main()
{
    Men M1{"Jack", 10};
    Men M2{"Tony", 20};
    my_swap(M1.age, M2.age); //pass the ages only
    std::cout << M1 << "," << M2 << std::endl;
}
```

<kbd>[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fhFwzqZ8GEuQUlw0)</kbd>

---

Or you can do something like:

```
//...
template <typename T>
void my_swap(T &a, T &b)
{
    T temp;
    temp.age = a.age;
    a.age = b.age;
    b.age = temp.age;
}

int main()
{
    Men M1{"Jack", 10};
    Men M2{"Tony", 20};
    my_swap(M1, M2); //pass the objects
    std::cout << M1 << "," << M2 << std::endl;
}
```

<kbd>[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iHoDPzLgLdRpn8Qj)</kbd>

This would only swap the `age` of the `Men` objects passed as arguments.

---

Using:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Men &M)
{
    os << M.name << " " << M.age;
    return os;
}
```

Both examples would output:

```
Jack 20,Tony 10
```

---

The line:

```
Men M3 = my_swap(M1, M2);
```

Is not correct, your template has `void` return type it cannot be assigned.

Comment: ok so this template function only work with men class?? i can't use it with primitive data types??

Comment: @logan_92, your original template works with primitive types also, yes, it's exactly what I do in the first code sample I posted, it swaps the age member of the 2 classes.

Comment: thank you @anastaciu , but i think for 1st approach we have to change my_swap() implementation to be  T temp.age = a???

Comment: @logan_92, I don't think it's needed, I added an online sample to the answer, check it out.

Comment: @logan_92, I also added an online sample for the second code, but the first is better IMO as it's more generic.

Answer (score 1):

Your `my_swap()` template function does a complete swap.  If you want it to swap only the `age` fields of `Men` parameters, and do a complete swap for other types, then you can use [**template specialization**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) to accomplish that, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void my_swap(T &a,T &b) // <-- primary template for all types
{
    T temp = std::move(a);
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(temp);

    /* or:
    using std::swap;
    swap(a, b);
    */
}

...

struct Men
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

template <>
void my_swap<Men>(Men &a, Men &b) // <-- specialization just for Men only
{
    int temp = a.age;
    a.age = b.age;
    b.age = temp;

    /* or:
    std::swap(a.age, b.age);
    */
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Men &M)
{
    os << M.name << " is " << M.age;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    int x{100};
    int y{200};
    my_swap(x, y);
    std::cout << x << "," << y << std::endl;

    Men M1{"Jack", 10};
    Men M2{"Tony", 20};
    my_swap(M1, M2);
    std::cout << M1 << "," << M2 << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
200,100
Jack is 20,Tony is 10
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/q54ClZ)

This way, the specialization is used whenever `my_swap()` is called with `T` set to `Men`, and the primary template is used whenever `my_swap()` is called with `T` set to any other type.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but is this normal function or template function ?? 
what does template <> mean , and how can you use my_swap<Men> in template function declaration ?? is this concept called template specialization??
template <>
void my_swap<Men>(Men &a, Men &b)

Comment: @logan_92 It is a [full specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) of a template function. `template <>` means the original template is being fully specialized with specific template parameter values, and so can have different code than the original. In this case, the specialized template is used for calls to `my_swap(Men&,Men&)` and the original template is used for all other calls to `my_swap()`. I suggest you read up on template specialization in any [decent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)